# Getting output of bool-type function

Tags: c, function, boolean, output, cs50

I have created this function in C in which I am checking the validity of the sides of the triangle;

How can I get its true/false output? (I have already tried by just calling it in main but it didn't work)

This is the function that I have created;

```
bool valid_triangle(float a, float b, float c)
{
    //Check if all sides are positive

    if (a <= 0 || b <=0 || c <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //Check if two sides are less than the third one
    if ((a + b <= c) || (b + c <= a) || (a + c <= b))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I want its bool type value as output in the terminal.

Comment: How are you calling it, and what happens?

Comment: _"I have already tried by just calling it in main"_: Well, [edit] and show what you have tried.

Comment: @Hadi, `(a + b <= c) || (b + c <= a) || (a + c <= b)` is an incorrect test for some values of `a, b, c`.   Consider `valid_triangle(1e10, 1, 1e10)` where `a + b` rounds to `a`.  Post values of `a, b, c` that "didn't work".